# How to have tpl for parent but not child?

Tags: 7, hooks, theming

I want to override the template for just `/user/` but not for `/user/edit` or `user/anythingelse`. Is there a way to do that?

For example, I made a page--user.tpl.php but it effects all of user's children.

Answer (score 0):

You are editing in wrong template file. You have to make theme changes in [user-profile.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user-profile.tpl.php/7).

For theme hook suggestions:

```
function themeName_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  // Go to user page.

  // Requires devel module.
  dpm($vars['theme_hook_suggestions']);
}
```

- There is a list of theme hooks in this [page](http://drupal.org/node/1089656)
- Theme [implementations](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/group/themeable/7) is Drupal 7